# Remove leading 0 from phone number in Woocommerce checkout field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the leading '0' from the phone number so that if a customer enters his/her phone number as '0856xxxxxxx' it turns to '856xxxxxxx' removing leading zero. I did some research on Internet and found that ltrim() function can be used so I updated my code in functions.php as below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'removeLeadingZero');

    function removeLeadingZero() {
        $billing_phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_phone');
    $billing_phone= ltrim($billing_phone, '0');
    }
```

Above code is not giving any output. Now the problem is I don't know how to return the updated value so that the final value becomes as desired.

Thanks

Comment: The function also doesn't return anything, nor does it accept any data, so...

Comment: can you please tell me how to proceed further, I do not know much of PHP coding

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try something like :

```
<?php

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'removeLeadingZero');

function removeLeadingZero() {
    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
       $_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/^0/', '', $_POST['billing_phone']);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver bro, I was trying to figure this out for 2 hours and this did the job. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My given code is able to remove the leading zero, the problem I am facing is to update the number in the checkout field.

```
$num = "0852360852";
if(stripos($num,"0") === 0){
    echo ltrim($num,"0");
}
```

Comment: My given code is able to remove the leading zero, the problem I am facing is to update the number in the checkout field.