# Add 0 to the beginning of phone numbers Woocommerce - After receiving Order #ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, preg-replace, checkout

I'm a php and wordpress newbie.
I have a woocommerce shop, where users are able to enter their phone number as [billing_phone] at woocommerce checkout page.
The mobile phones are 11 digits and they must include a ZERO at the beginning of it. Some users are adding the 0 to the beginning like 01234567891, while others simply do not.
What I want is to **check** the **[billing_phone]s after the purchase process** (**after they recieve the Order #ID**. and if it does not contain any 0 at the beginning add it automatically.

So if I go to **Woocommerce> Orders> Order details>** I should see an 11 digits with 0 under **Billing> Phone number section**.

I have read semi-related topics like [Remove zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565670/remove-leading-0-from-phone-number-in-woocommerce-checkout-field) and understood that it can be done by using the `preg_replace` [PHP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).
and came up with a solution like

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'AddZero');
function AddZero() {
if (isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && strlen['billing_phone'] == 10)) { //added lenght check to make sure if it's 10 digits
$_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/\0/', '', $_POST['billing_phone']);
// $_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('\*0\', '', $_POST['billing_phone']); //not working
// $_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/^0/', '0', $_POST['billing_phone']); // not working
// $_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/*0*/', '', $_POST['billing_phone']); //not working
// $_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/$0\d{9}*/', '', $_POST['billing_phone']); //not working
 } }
```

then changed the `if (isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && strlen['billing_phone'] == 10))` to `if (!(preg_match('/[0-9]{10}*/', $_POST['billing_phone'] )))`
nothing changed.
And finally tried what I learned from [regex basic tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

```
function AddZero() {
if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
$_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/^0/', '0', $_POST['billing_phone']); //the ^ will spot the first position of the given string, and then add 0 there.
    }
}
```

Not working either.

I don't know where I'm wrong, so any help is appreciated.
And please explain the answer if possible. I love to learn something new, not just using the given code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very simple if there would never be a number with two zeros.
If there is a leading 0, trim it off.
Then concatenate a leading 0.

```
$_POST['billing_phone'] = '0' + ltrim($_POST['billing_phone'],0);
```

Or
Test for a leading zero and add one if it does not already have one.

```
if (substr($_POST['billing_phone'],0,1) != '0' ){$_POST['billing_phone'] = '0' . $_POST['billing_phone'];}
```

I'm not so sure about your `&& strlen['billing_phone'] == 10)`.
What do you do if the length is 10 and has a leading zero?
I would probably add the zero if necessary then test the length.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. and you are right about the `strlen`. I used it to use the function only if it's 10 digits, but I didn't think it through about if it has a leading zero...
anyway I used the code as 
`add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'removeLeadingZero');
function removeLeadingZero() {
    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
       $_POST['billing_phone'] = '0' + ltrim($_POST['billing_phone'],0);
    }
}`
and it's not working. Am I using the right action? or not? I'd be grateful if you can provide a little bit more explanations.

Comment: I hope it is working well for you.  That was my choice solution.  I love simplicity.  Did you ignore the string length at first and deal with the length after making the first digit a zero?

Comment: Your answer gave me a better perspective of how should I work with coding logics, thanks a lot. And yes, I ignored the `strlen` totally as I saw the logic behind it was false and there will be no need for it. I want the function to fire after a payment is done and I only used it to check if it's 10 digits however as you said, users might add a leading zero and a 10 digits, so it will be 00!